# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Is there an easy way of checking multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (to be clear, I'm really taking $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by $x^2+1$). First, $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ are considered equivalent iff $x^2+1|p(x)-q(x)$. Let $p(x)-q(x)=\sum_{a=0}^{2n+1}c_ax^a$ where $c_a\in\mathbb{Z}$ (if the order of $p-q$ is even, just take $c_{2n+1}=0$). Then, $p\sim q$ iff $(p-q)(\pm i)=0$, which occurs iff
$$\sum\limits_{a=0}^n(-1)^ac_{2a}+\left(\sum\limits_{a=0}^n(-1)^ac_{2a+1}\right)i=0\,\iff\,\sum\limits_{a=0}^n(-1)^ac_{2a}=\sum\limits_{a=0}^n(-1)^ac_{2a+1}=0.$$
Therefore, if we consider the map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\to\mathbb{Z[i]}$ given by
$$\phi(r)=\sum\limits_{a=0}^n(-1)^ar_{2a}+\left(\sum\limits_{a=0}^n(-1)^ar_{2a+1}\right)i$$
where $r_a$ are the coefficients of $r$, then $\phi(r)=\phi(j)$ iff $r\sim j$. Moreover, each Gaussian integer has some element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ which maps to it under $\phi$, so $\phi$ is a bijection. Now, we need to check that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, which would imply that it is an isomorphism. It's easy to check that $\phi(1)=1$, and that $\phi(r+j)=\phi(r)+\phi(j)$. However, checking that $\phi(rj)=\phi(r)\phi(j)$ is a massive pain, and I really would rather not do the computation. I'm wondering if there's an easy way of checking that doesn't involve actually multiplying polynomials by hand and doing some manipulation.

Comment: Use the universal property of polynomial rings, namely that ring homomorphisms out of them are determined by where you send x. Here send x to i to get a surjection $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Check that the kernel is $(x^2+1)$--you've really already done that.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Sorry, but I don't understand. I don't see how the fact that the homomorphism is determined by where you send $x$ is helpful, because I don't know that this is a homomorphism, so surely it doesn't apply? It seems you're saying that if you take a surjection $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $x\mapsto i$, with kernel $x^2+1$, and apply it to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ that it's always a homomorphism?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the set of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to S$ for any ring $S$ is in bijection with $S$ itself, and this bijection is realized by asking where $x$ goes. This is the universal property in this case. Proving existence and uniqueness is an easy exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element of $\ \mathbb{Z}[x]/I\ $, where $\ I=\left\langle x^2+1\right\rangle\ $, can be written in the form $\ a+bx+I\ $, where $\ a+bx\in \mathbb{Z}[x]\ $ is the common remainder mod $\ x^2+1\ $ of all of the polynomials belonging to the equivalence class $\ a+bx+I\ $.  You don't need to write $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ out as a sum of coefficients and negative coefficients of some higher degree polynomial in the equivalence class, because you can simply show that
\begin{align}
(a+bx+I)(c+dx+I)&=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)x+bd(x^2+1)+I\\
&=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)x+I\ .
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Well, the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ contains a zero of the polynomial $x^2+1$, namely the residue class of $x$. Call it $[x]$. Then $[x]^2+1 = [x^2+1] = [0]$, i.e., $[x]^2 = [-1]$.

This shows that the arithmetic in $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is the same as in $\Bbb Z[i]$, where $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Anyway, given that one of the standard definitions of $\mathbf C$ is  $\mathbf R[X]/(X^2+1)$ …